# Why does Xilinx's Multiplier IP product bitwidth have an extra bit?

Tags: binary, vhdl, fpga, xilinx

Xilinx's complex multiplier IP documentation (PG104) has this to say about input and output bit-width setting:

> **Output Width**: Selects the width of the output product real and imaginary
> components. The values are automatically initialized to provide the full-precision
> product when the A and B operand widths are set. *The natural width of a complex
> multiplication is the sum of the input widths plus one.* If Output Width is set to be
> less than this natural width, the least significant bits are truncated or rounded, as
> selected by the next GUI field.

(Italics are mine.)  So if I multiply an 8-bit number by another 8-bit number, it wants to have the full precision output be a 17-bit number.  The inputs and outputs are assumed to be signed integers.

The largest magnitude signed number that 8 bits can represent is -128 (0x80).  128*128=16384 or 0x4000 which is 15 bits.  Add a sign bit and we're safe with a 16-bit output.

The largest positive is 127 (0x3F).  127*127=16129 or 0x3F01.  Again, safe with 16 bits.

What am I missing?  Why do they insist on the extra bit?

Answer (score 3):

It is a complex multiplication. That is sum of two multiplications.

pr = ar x br - ai x bi

pi = ar x bi + ai x br

The sum adds the extra bit.